# How smooth can non-nice associative operations on the reals be?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, associativity

Suppose ${*}:\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is $\mathcal C^k$ and *associative*. Does it necessarily satisfy the identity $a * b * c * d = a * c * b * d$?

For $k=0$ the answer is "no" -- a counterexample would be to let $x_1*x_2*\cdots*x_n$ to be the product of the $x_i$s up to and including the leftmost negative one (and the product of all of them if they are all nonnegative).

However, I can't find any counterexample for $k=1$. Will high enough $k$ guarantee that $a*b*c*d=a*c*b*d$? If not, will $\mathcal C^\infty$? Will "analytic"?

<s>Bonus question: If there is a $k$ that does force the identity, does the same $k$ work with $\mathbb R^n$ instead of $\mathbb R$?</s>
*(Edit: obviously not; multiplication of $[\,{}^{\strut x}_0\;{}^{\strut y}_1\,]$ matrices is very smooth.)*

The condition that $a*b*c*d\ne a*c*b*d$ for some $a,b,c,d$ is meant to force $*$ to be noncommutative while at the same time avoiding trivial solutions where $a*b*c$ doesn't depend on $b$.

*(This is a variant of a [question posed by Nikhil Mahajan](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053702/can-a-smooth-function-on-the-reals-form-a-non-commutative-semigroup) which unfortunately failed to get interesting answers due to a technicality.)*

Comment: Extremely partial answer: "Polynomial" _will_ guarantee $a*b*c*d=a*c*b*d$. The only associative polynomial operations on $\mathbb R$ (or any infinite field) are $$x*y=\begin{cases} x \\ y \\ x+y-K \\ M(x-K)(y-K)+K \end{cases}$$ for arbitrary constants $K$ and $M$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer assuming $\ast$ has a formal power series, that is,

$$X\ast Y=\sum_{p,q\geq 0}\alpha_{p,q}X^p Y^q$$

In order to be associative, we must have $\alpha_{0,0}=0$ **(why?)**, so assume $\alpha_{0,0}=0$.

It is first shown in Lemma 3.2 of [this article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00233-013-9533-4) that $\alpha_{0,1},\alpha_{1,0}\in\left\{0,1\right\}$.

It is then shown in Proposition 3.3 that if $\alpha_{1,0}=0$ and $\alpha_{0,1}=1$, then $X\ast Y=Y$.

Theorem 3.6 then shows that if $\alpha_{1,1}=0$, then $\ast=0$.

The case $\alpha_{1,0}=\alpha_{0,1}=0$ is shown to make $\ast$ commutative in Proposition 3.10. (side remark: Theorem 4.3 gives the following beautiful representation theorem: $\ast$ is associative iff it is of the form $a\ast b=f^{-1}(f(a)f(b))$ for some invertible formal power series $f$. )

The case $\alpha_{1,0}=\alpha_{0,1}=1$ is described on page 38 of [this book](https://books.google.nl/books?id=3vhkRUwfafcC&dq=Hazewinkel,%20M.:%20Formal%20Groups%20and%20Applications&hl=nl&source=gbs_navlinks_s), and is also shown to make $\ast$ commutative.

*Side remark on rational associative functions:* Theorem C2 of [this article](http://studmath.up.krakow.pl/index.php/studmath/article/view/118) gives the following representation theorem for associative *rational* functions: $X\ast Y=f(G(f^{-1}(X),f^{-1}(Y)))$, for some homografic function $f$ and $G$ one of $+$, $\cdot$, and $(X,Y)\mapsto\frac{X+Y}{1-XY}$.

Comment: What is the definition of "has a formal power series" here, and how does it exclude $a*b = a$? (And why is the power series in question "formal"? It had better define a real-analytic function if it is to represent an actual operator).